# vb.net: webclient not working?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

```
Dim instance As WebClient
Dim address As String
Dim avoids as string

address = "http://www.ecosavetech.com/avoid.txt"

avoids = instance.DownloadString(address)

MsgBox(avoids)
```

msgbox is not showing anything.

please help! i am not getting any errors either

i am using `Imports System.Net`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you shared, you didn't actually create the WebClient.

```
Dim instance as WebClient = new WebClient()
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you *sure* you are not getting any errors? Your code invokes the `DownloadString` method on a variable that is not referring to an instance (yet). You probably want do create a `WebClient` as well:

```
Dim instance As New WebClient()
Dim address As String
Dim avoids As Atring

address = "http://www.ecosavetech.com/avoid.txt"

avoids = instance.DownloadString(address)

MsgBox(avoids)
```